# Autodesk Forge data files

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-data-management

I am wondering when I upload rvt. file to Autodesk Forge a platform for translation.
Is it upload as files data to forge or it's only for translating it and it will stay on my local hard disk.
because when I refresh the page the files disappear, I was thinking if I should create a buklet and upæoad the files from azure or any cloud platform (not sure if am I right).

hope I can get an answer or if there an example that someone already has done it before.

thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

> I was thinking if I should create a buklet and upæoad the files from azure or any cloud platform (not sure if am I right).

Yes once a file is uploaded and translated then its derivatives (translated output) would stick around until they are explicitly [deleted](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-DELETE/) - see tutorial [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/prepare-file-for-viewer/).

If the files are on Azure then you will need to download to your server first or upload the file directly from a Azure web app or custom app hosted thereby (you can alternatively explore other options like Logic apps or Flow etc.) - our services can not reach out to the files proactively though.